# How to do margin notes in org-html-export?

Tags: org-mode

Is there an elegant way to have margin notes for `org-html-export-to-html`?

For example, as they appear in this page: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lat7h/blog/posts/124.html

Answer (score 1):

The link you provide looks a bit like [tufte-css](https://edwardtufte.github.io/tufte-css/). You might try [ox-tufte](https://github.com/dakrone/ox-tufte) to get the sidenotes and the right fonts, etc.